# Signals when document is modified/created

Tags: mongodb, qt, mongoengine

I have a Qt application that has user management and user notifications. In my MongoDB database, I have a notification collection. I want to connect a signal somehow to the Qt notification widget whenever a notification document is created.

Ideally I don't want to be running database queries on a QTimer, but that's the only thing I can think of at the moment. Any ideas?

Comment: Use a change stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the change stream then, here the [official doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/)
this mini example return a cursor on changes on the collection inventory

```
cursor = db.inventory.watch()
document = next(cursor)
```

Comment: Do I have to run this on a separate thread? Will it freeze my application?